# Seeking good practice advice: multisite in Drupal

Tags: drupal

I'm using multisite to host my client sites.

During development stage, I use subdomain to host the staging site, e.g. client1.mydomain.com.
And here's how it look under the SITES folder:

```
/sites/client1.mydomain.com
```

When the site is completed and ready to go live, I created another folder for the actual domain, e.g. client1.com.
Hence:

```
/sites/client1.com
```

Next, I created symlinks under client1.com for FILES and SETTINGS.PHP that points to the subdomain
i.e.

```
/sites/client1.com/settings.php --> /sites/client1.mydomain.com/settings.php

/sites/client1.com/files --> /sites/client1.mydomain.com/files
```

Finally, to prevent Google from indexing both the subdomain and actual domain, I created the rule in .htaccess to rewrite client1.mydomain.com to client1.com, therefore, should anyone try to access the subdomain, he will be redirected to the actual domain.

This above arrangement works perfectly fine. But I somehow feel there is a better way to achieve the above in much simplified manner. Please feel free to share your views and all advice is much appreciated.

Comment: I think it's normal way.

Comment: I am curious. Why not simply move the entire client1.mydomain.com to client1.com? Then there will be no need for URL rewriting also.

Comment: @abhaga I did that in the beginning, until I ran into problem with uploaded image paths, especially for images processed with Imagecache, the full path value is stored in the database, if I moved everything to client1.com, the images will stop showing up as they were still being "called" from the previous path, i.e. client1.mydomain.com...

Comment: If it is only imagecache, will flushing all the presets after moving do the trick?

Comment: Imagecache isn't the problem, though you will definitely have to clear your caches after migrating. ImageCache just uses whatever paths are stored in Drupal's core file interface, which includes the full path from Drupal's root directory ('sites/default/files...').  You'll have to run a find-and-replace update on any database tables that include links to files (the files table of course, profiles if you store pictures, nodes if you have links in content...).

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you want to reuse the **files/** directory and **settings.php** from your development domain, I'd suggest using the **default/** directory + symlinks to achieve your goals.

ie, during development

```
sites/default/settings.php
sites/default/files/
sites/client1.domain.com -> sites/default (symbolic link)
```

once you're ready to switch over to their domain:

```
sites/client1.com -> sites/default
```

You can then remove **client1.domain.com** from your virtual host (or continue with your rewrite, etc...).

It will accomplish the same as your method, but you get the added "protection" of all requests going to default in case you add an additional domain at a later date as an alias (for example).

Comment: Ah... I see what you mean there. It looks like a good solution for staging a single-site environment. But for multisite I guess this wont work. Thanks for your answer however, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply sharing core and module files between the sites, you can use a different symlink layout.

In my setup I have all of the shared files in a common, non-web-accessible directory:

```
/var/www/drupal
/var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules
```

then for each deployment, common files and folders are symlinked to those files.

```
/var/www/client1/public_html/index.php -> /var/www/drupal/index.php
/var/www/client1/public_html/includes  -> /var/www/drupal/includes
...
/var/www/client1/public_html/sites/all -> /var/www/drupal/sites/all
```

Then you can place the site's settings.php and any modules or themes for only that site in the default sites directory

```
/var/www/client1/public_html/sites/default
```

This layout also offers you the flexibility to override any common files as necessary, such as .htaccess.

To move from staging to production, you will just have to modify your virtual-host configuration from the staging to production domain name.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like a ton of symlinks, another option is using the Aliased Multi-Site Support patch:
http://drupal.org/node/231298#comment-1420180

This will allow you to specify in configuration that any requests for client1.domain.com should actually use /sites/client1.com/ instead of /sites/client1.domain.com/.

Then when you move to production, you can just remove the configuration setting (though it doesn't hurt anything if you don't).

This feature is part of Drupal 7, but as a new feature won't be added to Drupal 6.  More good news is that you won't even need to use it in D7 just for file paths, since instead of storing the full path to files in the database, they use a schema such as `public://` or `private://` which Drupal then maps to the correct file system path, allowing multiple storage types/locations with much better portability.